# How to properly destroy a shared unnamed semaphore used by multiple processes in C?

Tags: c, multiprocessing, semaphore

I have a program which creates some shared memory to share some data and some semaphores, write some data there and then other processes connect to it and read that data and do some operations, synchronising between them using the unnamed semaphores created by the first process.

After doing all the operations, is it possible to destroy the semaphores (with sem_destroy()) only if all the other processes are done? Or should it be better if I make the first process to wait for the other processes to finish their job and then destroy the semaphore? With this, I think I should implement any communication channel, but not sure how to do it.

EDIT: Providing some code

This is my writing process which creates the shared memory simplified (omitted the error handling):

```
int fd_shm = shm_open(SHM_NAME, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL,S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

/* Resize the memory segment */
ftruncate(fd_shm, sizeof(ShmExampleStruct))

/* Map the memory segment */
ShmExampleStruct *example_struct = mmap(NULL, sizeof(*example_struct), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED,fd_shm, 0);
close(fd_shm);

sem_init(&(example_struct->sem), 1, 1)
```

Inside the ShmExampleStruct I got the data and the semaphores.
After this code, it writes some data into example_struct

And the reading process code could be like this:

```
/* We open the shared memory */
int fd_shm = shm_open(SHM_NAME, O_RDONLY, 0);

/* Map the memory segment */
ShmExampleStruct *example_struct = mmap(NULL, sizeof(*example_struct), PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd_shm, 0);
close(fd_shm);
```

And then do some reading from example_struct

If I launch the writing process and then some reading processes, which is the best way to destroy the semaphore? In theory, the writing process should start and finish before the reading ones.

Comment: Are you using `sem_init` for your semaphores?  Are they located in the same shared memory along with the data?  How are you creating your shared memory?  Please provide a bit of C code to supplement your question.

Comment: I now provided some code. Yes, I use sem_init and the semaphores are in the same shared memory along with the data, and I create the shared memory with shm_open, ftruncate and then mmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in LPI from Michael Kerrish (page 1103), "an unnamed semaphore should be destroyed before its underlying memory is deallocated".

Moreover, it is stated in the book that "If the semaphore resides in a POSIX shared memory region", which is your case (`example_struct->sem`), "then the semaphore should be destroyed only after all processes are not using the semaphore and before the shared memory object is unlinked with `shm_unlink()`".

So, it is only safe to destroy an unnamed semaphore if no processes/threads are waiting on it. It results in undefined behaviour: (1) if a semaphore is destroyed when other processes/threads are blocked on it; and (2) if a destroyed semaphore is used.

To guarantee this in your case, you need to remove the shared memory object with the `shm_unlink()` function and only afterwards call `sem_destroy()`. For that you need to synchronize your processes in order to safely destroy the semaphore.

For instance, if you are creating processes (the readers and writters) using `fork()` in your parent process, then you can destroy the shared memory and semaphore in the parent process after all child processes complete. For synchronization you can use the `wait()` function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Then, I guess I'll have to implement a way to communicate between the processes so as the semaphore is destroyed only when all the processes are done.

Comment: I don't know how your code is structured but if you follow the traditional approach of `fork()` and `wait()`, you can clean your shared memory and semaphores after the `wait()`.

Comment: It would be a file with the writer program (which should create the shared memory and initialise the semaphores) and another file with the reader program. So they are not parent-child related, and using wait wouldn't be useful there I think

Comment: @XuChen If the writer and readers execute independently:  How many readers/consumers are there for the data?  If just one, then it can take care of the semaphore cleanup.  Otherwise you would have to define what qualifies as the _last_ process, and that process would do the cleanup.

Comment: @rtx13, For now, it's just one reader, so yes, it could be the one who destroys the semaphore. I was also wondering how to do this when there can be launched an undetermined number of readers

Comment: @XuChen If you have more than one reader, how do you define the _last_ reader after which it is safe to clean up the semaphore?

Comment: @rtx13 I thought about the writer just leaving a marker in the data when it finishes writing and who reads it can be the one who cleans up the semaphore.

Comment: @XuChen sure but say a reader consumes the data right now. How does this reader know whether or not there is going to be another reader for the data later?  If it has no way of knowing, it has no way of deciding to do the cleanup.  I'm just pointing out this is more of a design decision you have to make and then implement accordingly.

Comment: @rtx13 Aah, right, hadn't thought about that case. Yeah, it looks like it's more of a design decision than a standard way to do it. Thank you for your explanation!